# excess positional arguments, unpacking argument lists or tuples, and extended iterable unpacking

Tags: python, list, tuples

This question is going to be rather long, so I apologize preemptively.

In Python we can use * in the following three cases:

**I.** When defining a function that we want to be callable with an arbitrary number of arguments, such as [in this example](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists):

```
def write_multiple_items(file, separator, *args):
    file.write(separator.join(args))
```

In this case, the excess positional arguments are collected into a *tuple*.

**II.** The reverse case is when the arguments are already in either a *list* or a *tuple* and we wish to unpack them for a function call requiring separate positional arguments, such as [in this example](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
>>> range(3, 6)             # normal call with separate arguments
[3, 4, 5]
>>> args = [3, 6]
>>> range(*args)            # call with arguments unpacked from a list
[3, 4, 5]
```

**III.** Starting with Python 3, * is also used in the context of extended *list* or *tuple* unpacking, such as [in this example](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for tuples:

```
>>> a, *b, c = range(5)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

or for lists:

```
>>> [a, *b, c] = range(5)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

In both cases, all items from the iterable being unpacked that are not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions are assigned to a *list*.

So here's the question: in case **I** the extra args are collected into a *tuple*, while in case **III** the extra items are assigned to a *list*. Whence this discrepancy? The only explanation I could find was in PEP 3132 which says that:

> > Possible changes discussed were:
> >
> > [...]
> >
> > Make the starred target a tuple instead of a list. This would be
> >     consistent with a function's *args,
> >     but make further processing of the
> >     result harder.

However, from a pedagogical perspective this lack of consistency is problematic, especially given that if you wanted to process the result, you could always say list(b) (assuming b in the above examples was a tuple). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In Python we can use `*` in the
>   following three cases:

You mean **prefix** `*` , of course -- **infix** `*` is used for multiplication.

> However, from a pedagogical
>   perspective this lack of consistency
>   is problematic, especially given that
>   if you wanted to process the result,
>   you could always say list(b) (assuming
>   b in the above examples was a tuple).
>   Am I missing something?

I would say that the design problem (old and very long in the tooth!) is with the fact that when you're receiving arbitrary arguments you're getting them as a tuple, when a list would be more useful in many cases with no real downside (the tiny amount of extra processing and memory that may be needed to make a list instead of a tuple is negligible in the context of function call overhead -- *or* sequence unpacking, for that matter; the extra processing and memory needed to make a list **as well as** a tuple is really more annoying).

There's very little that you can do with a tuple but not a list -- basically, just hashing it (to use as a set item or dict key) -- while a list offers much more extra functionality, and not *just* for purposes of altering it... methods such as `count` and `index` are also useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In a nutshell what I'm hearing is that case **I** should have been designed to give a list.

Comment: @Alexandros, that is indeed my opinion -- but of course hindsight is 20/20, and that decision was made... I'm not sure when, but it was already in Python 1.5.2, over 11 years ago.

Answer (score 8):

You missed one.

**IV.** Also, in Python 3, a bare `*` in the argument list marks the end of positional arguments, allowing for [keyword-only arguments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

```
def foo(a, b, *, key = None):
    pass
```

This can be called `foo(1, 2, key = 3)` but not `foo(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks. Though not really an answer to my question, it is nice to have all the cases gathered in one thread.